# Software design: Too many classes?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm a layperson in terms of software design. I'm facing an "issue" that perhaps is solved by some well known technique/idiom/pattern which I would like to be told about.

I have an abstract base class basically defining one pure virtual member function and little else. Then I have several classes deriving from this one and overriding the said virtual function. I have now half a dozen such classes and the number is growing. The classes have just a few data members (very few, like a couple of doubles or that plus a function pointer) and they differ mainly by the way they perform a very short computation. I wonder if this indicates a bad design and is better dealt in some other way.

If appropriate, could someone point me at a relevant design pattern or idiom I should know of. Thanks.

**EDIT**

To clarify things, the abstract base class doesn't have any data members. Not all derived classes have data members. What I'm doing is to have coordinate transformations for integrals as classes. A given transformation only need a couple of parameters and sometimes the user-supplied function.

Comment: If the code is not duplicated then you're on the right track.

Comment: Does the abstract base class have any data members?

Comment: Agree with @Dialecticus, but the function pointer raises my eyebrow. Why a function pointer? Can you not design this into the specifics of the given subclass? As an aside, if you aren't already, [look at `std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). It may simplify use of the function pointer.

Comment: Its totally acceptable - and expected - to see that in O-O programming.  But at the same time some (like me) find it unnecessarily verbose and even confusing - not to mention sometimes hard to navigate and maintain - especially if you need a parallel class hierarchy for some reason (like some design patterns).  There are alternatives, e.g., data-driven designs where you can package everything much more compactly (syntax-wise) into a table organization - this is suitable if all the subclasses turn out to be uniform enough, and the class hierarchy is shallow.  There are other approaches too.

Comment: Templates can be very good. I removed 60 classes in a project by adding some templates and lambda magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your abstract base class does not have any data members (and it seems like it shouldn't if it has one pure virtual method), then there is a better pattern for this indeed. Suppose we have this code:

```
struct AbstractBase {
  virtual double calc(double) = 0;
  virtual ~AbstractBase() = default
}
```

Now, you have to inherit from this in order to use things dynamically elsewhere:

```
struct Derived : public AbstractBase { ... }

void BaseUser(AbstractBase& ab) { ... };
```

A less coupled solution would just be to write your class as a function object and use `std::function`.

```
struct Derived {
  double operator()(double x) { ... };
}

void User(std::function<double(double)> f);

User(Derived{}); // Calls user with Derived routine.
```

This has other advantages as well, for instance if some of your derived classes don't actually need state, then you can just write them as plain functions and still pass them around in `std::functions`. Yet another benefit is that you can write short functions inline as well now, because a lambda is a function object:

```
User([] (double x) { return 2*x; });
```

If you need more precision control than an abstract base class with a single virtual function call is ok, but when there's just one function in an interface I'd at least consider looking at function objects.

I wouldn't be concerned about the number of derived objects you have necessarily.

Comment: And even if your functions need state - you can write them as lambdas, capturing from the context what they need when they're built, and pass them around as functions ... or as lambdas!

Comment: Yes, the abstract base class doesn't have any data members. Also, not all derived classes have members. The actual thing I'm doing is to have coordinate transformations for an integral as classes. Some may receive a function from the user. I'll edit the OP to clarify that.

Comment: @davidbak Yes, but if the abstract base class of the OP had state, then that would not be possible to simulate with this design. My comment was specifically about state in the base class, not in the implementations.

Comment: @booNlatoT If not all derived members actually have data, then IMHO this is a strong reason to do it this way instead of with virtual inheritance. An actual function is clearer for a stateless function than writing a functor.

Comment: I've tried it. std::function plus lambdas seems perfect for what I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

an abstract base class with one virtual function sounds almost exactly like a `std::function<>` containing a lambda.

for example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using op = std::function<int()>;

    int x = 7;
    int y = 5;
    auto a = [x, y]() -> int { return x + y; };
    auto b = [x, y]() -> int { return x - y; };

    auto ops = std::vector<op> { a, b };
    for (const auto& o : ops)
    {
        std::cout << o() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In the end, a lambda is just a shorthand form of writing a class which captures (copies) some objects or references to objects and exposes a call operator.

A std::function is a polymorphic adaptor for such classes.

Using lambdas may save you some typing. Whether it adds or subtracts to the semantic expression of your code (which is arguably more important) is another matter.

Comment: And you don't even need the std::function - if you stick with `auto` and `decltype` you can use "naked" lambdas which, I understand, can be more compact and efficient than std::function if you don't need the generality that that provides.

Comment: @davidbak I am assuming the OP needs a polymorphic interface since he's using an ABC. Without example code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: yes, example code would have been nice.  I get what you're saying about a polymorphic interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is a saying: DRY. **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself. Other than overriding that pure virtual method, if there is any other form of duplicate code, then that may be a sign that revision is needed. If you have lots of classes and each one is unique in functionality, then that is OK.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to fully comment without seeing an example. In general, the fact that you have many classes, each of which does only a small (set of) operation(s), does not necessarily indicate bad design. You should try as much as possible to build classes using DRY (don't repeat yourself) and SOLID (see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))) principles.

Answer (score 0):

If the operations can be composed, then you should try to compose the objects in order to compose the operations. A class should only really do one thing, so you do not necessarily have a problem.

Comment: I'd reword that a little. A class should represent one thing. It can do many things.